# How to improve Dask performance for parsing json from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, dask

I am comparing a normal script that loads data from s3 and parses the json content. I thought maybe Dask would be faster at these kind of tasks. However the Dask script that I am using seems to be much slower than the ruby script benchmark.

Here is the script:

```
import time
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client
import ujson
from s3fs import S3FileSystem

fs = S3FileSystem(anon=False)
client = Client()

target_id=2
target_path = "s3://bucket/log/2014/07/%d/"
target_path_dirs = [fs.ls(target_path % x) for x in range(10,21)]
target_paths = ['s3://'+x+"/*.json" for x in sum(target_path_dirs,[])]

t0 = time.time()
records = db.read_text(target_paths).map(ujson.loads)
filtered_records = records.filter(
       lambda x: x['id'] == target_id)

r_c = filtered_records.compute()
t1 = time.time()
total = t1 - t0
print(total)
```

The ruby script downloads the files with `aws s3 cp --recursive` and then goes on to parse the json files. It only takes 3 minutes and the final file is 1.5 Mb. What could be the problem?

I am running this script on a single machine but it has 8 cores and 32GiB of RAM and all cores seem to be working when running the Dask script.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like network was the bottleneck. I downloaded the data first and it parsed in 8 seconds which was faster than the script which took 2 minutes parsing.